# How to compare difference between two date time stamp in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 02 columns, TradeDate and TradeExecDate with format in dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.00000000 AM/PM
How do I get to find the difference between the date timestamp is greater than 01.

That is the TradeDate and TradeExecDate are different, not same date but different date.

Tx

Comment: What datatype are these columns? And what do you mean by "How do I get to find the difference between the date timestamp is greater than 01"? Greater than 1 what?

Comment: Sorry , by 1 I meant, greater than one day

Comment: and what types are these columns? timestamps? dates? strings?

Comment: data type is Date

Comment: Sorry its timestamp.

Comment: "Soorry its timestamp".  Then it is _not_ "with format in dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.00000000 AM/PM "  DATE and the various flavors of TIMESTAMP do not have formats, in the common understanding of that.  They are of oracle's internal binary format.  The format "dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.00000000 AM/PM " is merely the result of applying a to_char() function to the TIMESTAMP, to produce a character string that is recognized by humans as _representing_ a DATE or a TIMESTAMP.   Read more about it here: https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Answer (score 2):

As you have timestamps, the difference is [an interval datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TradeExecDate - TradeDate > interval '1' day
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) about datetime/interval arithmetic.